# Writing date to wvdial with AT command to set GPS module time

Tags: shell, date, gps, at-command

I have a GPS module that loses its time when the machine is powered off. Without the correct time, no GPS fix.

I'm using `wvdial` to send Hayes commands to the GPS module at `/dev/ttyUSB3`. Time should be set at boot time, I guess with an init script. I get the date in the format like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
DATE=`date +%m/%d/%y,%H:%M:%S`
echo $DATE > setGPStime.txt
```

Than wvdial has to send time to GPS with

```
AT+CCLK=<time>
```

How do I read the output of the date command to set the time with `wvdial`?
How do I do this in shell script or is there a "better" way?

I am not very familiar with shell script. Is there anyone who has any good ideas to do this or to send me in the right direction?

Comment: the gps device will get the time via satellites. but this then need more time.

Answer (score 1):

You can read from a file into a variable like this:

```
fromFile=$( cat setGPStime.txt )
```

However, if you are calling `wvdial` from the same script where you are calling `date`, there's no need for a temporary file. Just use `$( date %m/%d/%y,%H:%M:%s )` wherever you
were going to use the value read from a file. Something like this, perhaps (I'm not familiar with the usage of `wvdial`)?

```
wvdial "AT+CCLK=$( date %m/%d/%y,%H:%M:%s )"
```

However, AlexWien is right. This is likely only setting the display time on your module, not anything actually used for positioning. GPS uses a time signal with (approximately) nanosecond precision, which isn't going to be achieved by any on-board hardware. The correct time is maintained on the satellites themselves, and the necessary values are transmitted on the signal received by your module. Your module only needs to do the math on the received signals, not maintain a clock itself.